# Angular 16: How to Load Translations from .po Files with ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am working on an Angular 16 upgrade project and I need to load translations from .po files into my application. Previously, I used ngx-translate along with TranslatePoHttpLoader to accomplish this (from biesbjerg), but it seems that TranslatePoHttpLoader hasn't been updated for Angular 16.
I also tried using the one from @fjnr, and from a few more with no luck though
Here's what I used to have in my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { TranslatePoHttpLoader } from '@fjnr/ngx-translate-po-http-loader';

// ...

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslatePoHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.po');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  // Other module configurations...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I've tried updating the package and importing TranslatePoHttpLoader as before, but it doesn't seem to work with Angular 16. It throws an error about upward dependencies (angular16).
I tried to make it work with other po loaders as well (a big search checking their individual package.json for compatibility), one of them was `po-loader` and web-pack-po-loader` but those coding attempts failed too.
When i look around at npmjs.com, fo other po loaders they are minimally discussed (some have even empty readme files).

Maybe I missed the discussions around the po loaders, i tried to look at various places on the internet but it's been over 5 years, so such discussions might have beene removed. I note that ngx-translate/core seems mainly build around json, so perhaps a conversion is needed but i dont know, as our customer generates the po files, they do not typically build using angular website, so working with a .pot and .po files is important to me, that still should work.

Question:

- Is there an alternative to TranslatePoHttpLoader that works with Angular 16 for loading translations from .po files?
- What is the recommended approach for handling .po files in Angular 16, given that po editors are still widely used for translations?

I appreciate any guidance or code examples that can help me address this issue and continue working with .po files in my Angular 16 project. Thank you!

Comment: did you find a working `po` loader. I too am upgrading an angular project to angular 16 where `po` files are used for translation.

Comment: No i did not, I ended up converting them to json by a script
here is my vbs script but its not yet perfect doesnt handle all cases (i noticed).
need to fix it (will do within a few months, i have other priorities first).
see https://github.com/PGTBoos/PO2Json  I must remind to fix it next year, but your free to fix it too, its just vbs i had only limmited time, as other projects have priorities too